# Need to stop the date picker copying into the 2 textviews

Tags: android

I have 2 imagebuttons and 2 textviews. The following code writes the same date to the 2 textviews which i dont want, when i click one image button is meant to write to edittext1 and when the second is clicked it should write to edittext2

Here is my code

```
public void selectDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }



    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        DepartDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        DepartDate.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);


    }

    public void populateSetDate1(int year1, int month1, int day1) {

        ReturnDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ReturnDate.setText(month1+"/"+day1+"/"+year1);

    }



    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
            populateSetDate1(yy, mm+1, dd);

        }
```

Comment: You are calling two methods `populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
         populateSetDate1(yy, mm+1, dd);` in on date set

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment(view);
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}



public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day, View v) {
    DepartDate = v;
    DepartDate.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);


}




public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private View view;
    public SelectDateFragment(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
        populateSetDate1(yy, mm+1, dd);

    }
```

Comment: I need the datepicker to write to the two textareas via using the imagebutton which is displaying the datepicker. I have 2 textareas and 2 datepickers. 1 works perfectly but when i try to add to the 2nd textarea it overwrites the first textarea and add's to the second textarea. Anybody got any ideas how i could change my code. The above doesn't do what i was asking but Thanks anyway!

Comment: Not quite sure where the first image button is being called because the first one is working perfectly with the code i've provided. Was hoping somebody could point out where that is so i could add another for the second one. I think it'd solve the problem i'm having then..

Comment: if there is no code like setOnclickevent in your code pls check the androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Yeah, How will i send it to you? Its too long to post over this. Thanks for your help by the way
        

        
        }
        
            });
     }
     
     
    }

Comment: just send to leiweibo@gmail.com